# Secure Login Equivalent on OS X

Tags: windows, security, login

On Windows you can configure "Secure Login" so that you have to press <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delect</kbd> to show the login screen like so:

[image: Secure Login Windows]

Does this feature exist on OS X or is there a third-party application that can achive this?

Comment: Umm... but why?

Comment: Same reason why you would do this on Windows.  Prevent a fake login screen from being shown that grabs your credentials.

Comment: I don't think that can happen in Mac, also I only see these on public computers.

Comment: It's a setting controlled in group policy and is enabled when you join a Windows computer into a AD domain.

Comment: @ecnepsnai, CAD can be enable on a stand-alone PC running Windows and doesn't have to be connected to anything for that matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** No.  This feature does not exist on Macs.

On a side note, it's also useless in Windows too.

A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away, CTRL+ALT+DEL sent a hardware interrupt to the PC's BIOS (which would immediately reboot the computer in the DOS days).

That interrupt also had the happy side-effect of breaking things like keyloggers and programs designed to steal your password, so when Windows NT arrived on the scene, Microsoft trapped that interrupt to prove that you were a real, live human sitting in front of a keyboard.

That has not been the case for many, many years.  I have no idea why we're still dragging this stupid three-finger salute around after all these years (tradition maybe?)  It offers no meaningful security these days and I personally disable it with Group Policy on every domain I administer.